# Callback Not Working in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to handle asynchronous calls in NodeJs. Here is my code:

```
function getUserFromToken(token) {
  decodeJWT(token, function (err, data) {
    console.log("Call back Worked");
  })
}

function getUserProfile(user_id, username, hashPass, callback) {
  let sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, username FROM User where user_id=? AND username=? AND password=?";

  db.query(sql, [user_id, username, hashPass], function (err, result) {
    if (err) callback(err, null);
    else callback(null, result)
  });
}

function decodeJWT(token, cb) {
  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function (err, decoded) {

    if (err) res.status(401).send({auth: false, message: miscConstants.INVALID_TOKEN});

    const {user_id} = decoded;
    const {username} = decoded;
    const {hashPass} = decoded;

    getUserProfile(user_id, username, hashPass, res, function (err, profile) {

      cb(null,'yo');
    });

  });
}
```

The callback used in the `getUserProfile` function works but, it never reaches the `console.log("Call back Worked");`. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually have a function named callback somewhere?

Comment: handle error properly in decodeJWT you are calling getUserProfile , check if its throwing err. Its better to use promise you dont need to handle all errors

Comment: How did you find - _The callback used in the getUserProfile function works_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is not being called because your call to `getUserProfile` is passing 5 parameters `user_id, username, hashPass, res, function`, while the function is expecting only 4:

```
getUserProfile(user_id, username, hashPass, res, function (err, profile) {...}
```

And the function:

```
function getUserProfile(user_id, username, hashPass, callback)
```

To make it work, just delete the parameter `res` in the `getUserProfile` call.